# PIL - Convert GIF Frames to JPG

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, gif, jpeg

I tried to convert an gif to single images with Python Image Library,
but it results in weird frames

The Input gif is:

[Source Image http://longcat.de/gif_example.gif](http://longcat.de/gif_example.gif)

In my first try, i tried to convert the image with Image.new to an 
RGB image, with 255,255,255 as white background - like in any other
example i've found on the internet:

```
def processImage( infile ):

    try:
        im = Image.open( infile )
    except IOError:
        print "Cant load", infile
        sys.exit(1)

    i = 0

    try:
        while 1:

            background = Image.new("RGB", im.size, (255, 255, 255))
            background.paste(im)
            background.save('foo'+str(i)+'.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=80)

            i += 1
            im.seek( im.tell() + 1 )

    except EOFError:
        pass # end of sequence
```

but it results in weird output files:

[Example #1 http://longcat.de/gif_example1.jpg](http://longcat.de/gif_example1.jpg)

My second try was, to convert the gif in an RGBA first, and then use
its transparency mask, to make the transparent pieces white:

```
def processImage( infile ):

    try:
        im = Image.open( infile )
    except IOError:
        print "Cant load", infile
        sys.exit(1)

    i = 0

    try:
        while 1:

            im2 = im.convert('RGBA')
            im2.load()

            background = Image.new("RGB", im2.size, (255, 255, 255))
            background.paste(im2, mask = im2.split()[3] )
            background.save('foo'+str(i)+'.jpg', 'JPEG', quality=80)

            i += 1
            im.seek( im.tell() + 1 )

    except EOFError:
        pass # end of sequence
```

which results in an output like this:

[Example #2 http://longcat.de/gif_example2.jpg](http://longcat.de/gif_example2.jpg)

The advantage over the first try was, that the first frame looks pretty good
But as you can see, the rest is broken

What should i try next?

Edit:

I think i came a lot closer to the solution

[Example #3 http://longcat.de/gif_example3.png](http://longcat.de/gif_example3.png)

I had to use the palette of the first image for the other images,
and merge it with the previous frame (for gif animations which use
diff-images)

```
def processImage( infile ):

    try:
        im = Image.open( infile )
    except IOError:
        print "Cant load", infile
        sys.exit(1)

    i = 0

    size        = im.size
    lastframe   = im.convert('RGBA')
    mypalette   = im.getpalette()

    try:
        while 1:

            im2 = im.copy()
            im2.putpalette( mypalette )

            background = Image.new("RGB", size, (255,255,255))

            background.paste( lastframe )
            background.paste( im2 )
            background.save('foo'+str(i)+'.png', 'PNG', quality=80)

            lastframe = background

            i += 1
            im.seek( im.tell() + 1 )

    except EOFError:
        pass # end of sequence
```

But i actually dont know, why my transparency is black, instead of white
Even if i modify the palette (change the transparency channel to white)
or use the transparency mask, the background is still black

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all, `JPEG` doesn't support transparency! But that's not the only problem.. As you move to the next frame of the `GIF` the `palette` information is lost ([problem witn PIL?](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/image-sig/2008-November/005273.html)) - so `PIL` is unable to correctly convert to the `RGBA` framework (Hence the first frame is okish, but all the others are screwy). So the work-around is to add the `palette` back in for every frame, (which is what you were doing in your last code example, but your trouble was that you were saving as `RGB` not `RGBA` so you had no alpha/ transparency channel. Also you were doing a few unnecessary things..). Anyhow, here are the .png's with transparency and the corrected code, hope its of some use :)

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

```
import Image
import sys

def processImage(infile):
    try:
        im = Image.open(infile)
    except IOError:
        print "Cant load", infile
        sys.exit(1)
    i = 0
    mypalette = im.getpalette()

    try:
        while 1:
            im.putpalette(mypalette)
            new_im = Image.new("RGBA", im.size)
            new_im.paste(im)
            new_im.save('foo'+str(i)+'.png')

            i += 1
            im.seek(im.tell() + 1)

    except EOFError:
        pass # end of sequence

processImage('gif_example.gif')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I use paste with the last frame, because some gifs uses diffs for each frame!

Comment: Uhm, replacing the palette like that will give incorrect results when the frames have different palettes. One example of that is the image http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/bunny_bgnd.gif (I think, not sure if I'm copying & pasting the right links). The other problem I see might be related to differences between PIL versions, but I don't get the same result as yours (I get grey areas in all the frames except the first, where it should have been transparent). The same happens for a gif like http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/anim_opt/bunny_bgnd_opttrans.gif.

Comment: @mmgp - hmm, yep I can see that frames with different palettes could pose a problem. I agree your getting different results might be a version issue. Unfortunetly, I don't have time to look at this at the moment, if you have a fix please edit my answer, or add you own. nice one.

Comment: @fraxel PIL doesn't make it easy. I found this answer because a newer question linked to it, I tried something at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14550885/1832154, but this still fails for another type of GIF animation (not these ones I liked in the earlier comment).

Answer (score 4):

When viewing an image on an image viewer, even when transparency is set to zero, it tends to display the image as black. One way to be sure that your image is truly transparent is to merge it over another. The 'emoticon' should be seen whilst not obstructing the other image.Try:

```
background = Image.open('someimage.jpg') #an existing image
foreground = Image.open('foo.jpg') #one of the above images
background.paste(foreground, (0,0), foreground)
background.save('trial.jpg') #the composite image
```

Theoretically, if you open 'trial.jpg' in the image viewer and the content of the initial image is preserved and on top of it lies the foo image then you'll know for sure if it's just the image viewer and your images are fine...

Comment: .jpeg doesn't support transparency :(

Answer (score 3):

[source here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2000-May/036017.html)

```
Image.open('image.gif').convert('RGB').save('image.jpg')
```

Comment: OP was asking about converting an animated (multiframe) gif to a series of jpegs; this only saves the first frame

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This works for me. The following example shows converting image.gif to 8 jpg format images with white background.

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL import GifImagePlugin


def gif2jpg(file_name: str, num_key_frames: int, trans_color: tuple):
    """
    convert gif to `num_key_frames` images with jpg format
    :param file_name: gif file name
    :param num_key_frames: result images number
    :param trans_color: set converted transparent color in jpg image
    :return:
    """
    with Image.open(file_name) as im:
        for i in range(num_key_frames):
            im.seek(im.n_frames // num_key_frames * i)
            image = im.convert("RGBA")
            datas = image.getdata()
            newData = []
            for item in datas:
                if item[3] == 0:  # if transparent
                    newData.append(trans_color)  # set transparent color in jpg
                else:
                    newData.append(tuple(item[:3]))
            image = Image.new("RGB", im.size)
            image.getdata()
            image.putdata(newData)
            image.save('{}.jpg'.format(i))


gif2jpg("image.gif", 8, (255, 255, 255))  # convert image.gif to 8 jpg images with white background
```

Comment: This is great, thank you for this!!

Comment: Great approach!