# Saving an animated GIF in Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

(Python 3.4, PIL 1.1.7, Pillow 2.5.1)

I expected this to copy the original GIF.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(filename)
im.save('temp.gif')
```

Instead, it saves the first frame as a still.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just answered the same question here ^^: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24688649/1144523. Basically, Image let's you work with gifs one image at a time.

Comment: Hm, that's unfortunate. There doesn't seem to be a real GIF module for Python.

Comment: Since it's not an exact duplicate, I'm hesitant to close it as duplicate. Can you post your last sentence as an answer?

Comment: machow's question is about reading GIF, not writing GIF.

Comment: @Damian, it answered the question of, "Why isn't this working?" Also, the last sentence in machow's answer in that question linked to an answer for saving GIFs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a multiple frame image using Python PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540119/how-to-create-a-multiple-frame-image-using-python-pil)

Comment: @CeesTimmerman While one of the answers also addresses this question, that question was edited to ask for a TIFF. The question is related, but not exactly a duplicate (yet).

Comment: @leewz The code is the same, just replace "tiff" by "gif".

Comment: @CeesTimmerman Your answer is the same, but the question doesn't quite overlap. Someone needs to edit that question.

Comment: Note that currently selected answer is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the script found on the Pillow Github, [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/pillow-scripts/blob/master/Scripts/gifmaker.py).

```
 from PIL import ImageSequence
 from PIL import Image
 import gifmaker
 sequence = []

 im = Image.open(....)

 # im is your original image
 frames = [frame.copy() for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(im)]
 
 # write GIF animation
 fp = open("out.gif", "wb")
 gifmaker.makedelta(fp, frames)
 fp.close()
```

Comment: Does this work with Pillow 3?  The module `gifmaker.py` that you link to doesn't define `makedelta`.

Comment: I fixed the first two imports to `from PIL import ImageSequence` and `from PIL import Image` but what should be done with gifmaker?

Comment: Looks like it was removed.

Answer (score 27):

Version that requires only [pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving) and works:

```
from PIL import Image

width = 300
height = 300
im1 = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (255, 0, 0))
im2 = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (255, 255, 0))
im3 = Image.new("RGBA", (width, height), (255, 255, 255))
im1.save("out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=[im2, im3], duration=100, loop=0)
```

using existing images:

```
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open('a.png')
im2 = Image.open('b.png')
im3 = Image.open('c.png')
im1.save("out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=[im2, im3], duration=100, loop=0)
```

And, as too low versions of pillow are silently failing here is as a bonus version with a library version check:

```
from packaging import version
from PIL import Image

im1 = Image.open('a.png')
im2 = Image.open('b.png')
im3 = Image.open('c.png')
if version.parse(Image.PILLOW_VERSION) < version.parse("3.4"):
    print("Pillow in version not supporting making animated gifs")
    print("you need to upgrade library version")
    print("see release notes in")
    print("https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/3.4.0.html#append-images-to-gif")
else:
    im1.save("out.gif", save_all=True, append_images=[
             im2, im3], duration=100, loop=0)
```

Answer (score 14):

One can see that the new version of gifmaker script simply uses save method with special kwargs for GIF.

As the documentation states (https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/image-file-formats.html#saving-sequences):

> When calling save(), if a multiframe image is used, by default only the first frame will be saved. To save all frames, the save_all parameter must be present and set to True.
>
> If present, the loop parameter can be used to set the number of times the GIF should loop, and the duration parameter can set the number of milliseconds between each frame.

Comment: But I couldn't find anything in the documentation about how to create a multiframe image from scratch rather than from another GIF.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem. It appears that Pillow does not provide any interface to do that.

Comment: Actually now it does: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/releasenotes/3.4.0.html#append-images-to-gif

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered same problem. I solved it by making **save_all=True**. So you don't need to use gifmaker library anymore.