# Creating an animated GIF with Pillow 6.2.0 seemingly doesn't append all images and ignores duration setting

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library, animated-gif

I am trying to create and save a GIF from a set of PNG files.

```
pics=[]
for plot_path in plot_paths:
    img = Image.open(plot_path)
    pics.append(img)
pics[0].save(save_dir+'/truestrain.gif', format='gif', save_all=True, append_images=pics[1:], duration=10, loop=0)
```

The output is a gif file, of the correct name, but only using the first PNG file, and 10 seconds long.

`save_all=True` should prompt it to use all of the images in `append_images=pics[1:]`, but that doesn't seem to be working.

`duration=10` should set the duration between frames as 10ms, seems to be interpreted as total time 10s (contrary to the Pillow documentation?)

I have seen a relevant previous post, which agrees with the method I am using, but still having problems ([Saving an animated GIF in Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688802/saving-an-animated-gif-in-pillow)). I've also checked this follows the documentation (https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/image-file-formats.html).

Comment: I am currently running this from a Jupyter notebook in Anaconda distribution.

Comment: Did you check your version of PILLOW, as [one of those answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54379281) suggested?

Comment: Yep, no issues with version as far as I can see. Edit: Version Is 6.2.0

Comment: Is your ``plot_path`` correct?

Comment: Yep, I can test it using pics[2500] (For example), which displays the correct image in the console.

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out, the GIF is being created correctly. Neither windows Photos or VLC was able to play it for some reason. I downloaded an alternative GIF viewer and the file is as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me with your version 6.2.0. I just tested different settings for `duration` and can definitely see the difference:

```py
from PIL import Image
assert Image.__version__ == "6.2.0"
frames = [Image.open(f"frame_{i:0>3}.png") for i in range(44)]
for duration in [10, 100, 1000]:
    frames[0].save(f"result_{duration}.gif", format="gif", save_all=True, append_images=frames[1:], duration=duration, loop=0)
```

There is a limit to duration precision of the GIF format itself. But it should be one hundredth of a second, so your `duration=10` should be fine.