# Using PIL to generate gif from many png files

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to combine many png images into a gif file using this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57751793/3084842), but it only saves one png in the gif. What am I doing wrong? My MWE is

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import glob

thist = 4 # total time
tstep = 0 # time step

while thist>=tstep:

    x = np.linspace(0,2,100)
    y = np.sin(x*(thist-tstep)) # complicated calculation

    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
    ax = plt.subplot(111)

    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.savefig('mytest'+str(tstep)+'.png')

    tstep += 1

fp_in = "mytest*.png"
fp_out = "myimage.gif"

# https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/image-file-formats.html#gif
img, *imgs = [Image.open(f) for f in sorted(glob.glob(fp_in))]
img.save(fp=fp_out, format='GIF', append_images=imgs,
         save_all=True, duration=200, loop=0)
```

In addition,

```
>> print(glob.glob(fp_in))

['mytest0.png', 'mytest1.png', 'mytest2.png', 'mytest3.png', 'mytest4.png']

>> print(imgs)

[<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1000x600 at 0x7F8FCEB33240>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1000x600 at 0x7F8FCEB33400>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1000x600 at 0x7F8FCEB33470>, <PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=1000x600 at 0x7F8FCEBACB38>]
```

Comment: first you could check what you ge with `glob.glob(fp_in)` and what you get in `imgs`.

Comment: it looks like both `glob.glob(fp_in)` and `imgs` contain the correct number of images

Comment: shorter and more readable: `for tstep in range(thist):` and it doesn't need `tstep += 1`

Comment: your code gives me animated GIF. But not all programs display animated GIFs. I tested it in web browser Firefox.

Comment: that's strange - it doesn't work in any of my browsers or apps. I'm using jupyter notebook 5.6.0, Python 3.5.2

Comment: did you try to run it without Jupyter? Or maybe you should use newer Python with newest module `pillow`.

Comment: normally I would use in console program [imagemagick](https://imagemagick.org/) instead of `python` to generate `gif` - something like `convert test*.png myimage.gif`. OR I would run it in Python with subprocess. `imagemgick` is also used by Python module [Wand](https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.6/)

Comment: it works outside of jupyter. but I must use jupyter to do my data processing - this MWE shows that it would be a problem for generating gifs (no I'm not allowed to install imagemagick or wand)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned in comments the code you posted works on the latest Python + pillow distribution. Possible issue with your pillow version, similar issue is mentioned here [PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile images can't be saved as GIFs in 7.1.1](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/4578).

Solution in that issue is to

1. update Pillow
2. .copy() all frames
3. use jpg instead of png.

Comment: can you show me how to `copy()` all frames? thanks (3. doesn't work, saving as jpg still gives non-moving gifs in jupyter)

Comment: what version of pillow are you using? note that Pillow is the PIL-fork with many updated features and is required in the SO post you are following

Comment: `PIL.PILLOW_VERSION` gives me `3.1.2`

Comment: that's way too old. [this so post suggests you need at least 3.4 to use the append_images argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688802/saving-an-animated-gif-in-pillow/54379281#54379281)