# Gifs Not Animating On Flask

Tags: python, flask

In this flask application I am trying to upload gifs in the posts, they do appear but they donot show any animation. This is my code below:

```
def save_memes(form_pfps):
    randomizer = secrets.token_hex(8)
    _, f_ext = os.path.splitext(form_pfps.filename)
    picture_fn = randomizer + f_ext
    picture_path = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static/memes', picture_fn)
    i = Image.open(form_pfps).convert('RGB')
    i.save(picture_path)
    return picture_fn


@app.route("/mem/new", methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def new_post():
    form = CreatePost()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if 'meme' in request.files:
            meme_file = request.files['meme']
            if meme_file.filename != '':
                meme_filename = save_memes(meme_file)
                mem = Mems(title=form.title.data, description=form.description.data, author=current_user, meme=meme_filename)
                db.session.add(mem)
                db.session.commit()
                flash('New Mem Was Created!', 'success')
                return redirect(url_for('home1'))
        else:
            flash('Error: No meme image provided.', 'danger')

    return render_template('create_post.html', style="create_post.css", title="New Post", form=form)
```

This code saves the gifs or png files to the static/memes folder.

and these are all the imports:

```
import os
import secrets
from PIL import Image
from flask import render_template, url_for, flash, redirect, request
from werkzeug.exceptions import HTTPException
from mem import app, db, bcrypt
from mem.forms import SignUp, signin, UpdateProfileForm, CreatePost, Search
from mem.models import User, Mems
from flask_login import login_user, current_user, logout_user, login_required
from flask import current_app
```

I tried to convert the files to RGB but it didnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Saving an animated GIF in Pillow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688802/saving-an-animated-gif-in-pillow)

Comment: Alternatively, save files as is without recoding?