# Python + Pillow + Images2Gif - incorrect color of GIF frames

Tags: python, animated-gif, python-imaging-library

I'm using following code to add watermark to animated GIF images. My problem is that all GIF frames except the first one have incorrect colors in result. Would you know how to fix the color of frames? Thank you.

```
def add_watermark(in_file, watermark_file, watermark_position, watermark_ratio, out_file, quality=85):
   img = Image.open(in_file)
   watermark_layer = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, (0,0,0,0))
   watermark_img = Image.open(watermark_file).convert('RGBA')
   watermark_img.thumbnail((img.size[0]/watermark_ratio, 1000), Image.ANTIALIAS)
   alpha = watermark_img.split()[3]
   alpha = ImageEnhance.Brightness(alpha).enhance(0.95)
   watermark_img.putalpha(alpha)
   watermark_layer.paste(watermark_img, count_watermark_position(img, watermark_img, watermark_position))
   frames = images2gif.readGifFromPIL(img, False)
   frames_out = []
   for frame in frames:
       frames_out.append(Image.composite(watermark_layer, frame, watermark_layer))
   images2gif.writeGif(out_file, frames_out, duration=0.5)
```

To complete example, i provide also code of helper function:

```
def count_watermark_position(img, watermark, position):
   if position == 'right_bottom':
      return img.size[0] - watermark.size[0], img.size[1] - watermark.size[1]
   if position == 'center':
      return (img.size[0] - watermark.size[0])/2, (img.size[1] - watermark.size[1])/2
   if position == 'left_bottom':
       return 0, img.size[1] - watermark.size[1]
   if position == 'left_top':
       return 0, 0
   if position == 'right_top':
      return img.size[0] - watermark.size[0], 0
   raise AttributeError('Invalid position')
```

[Source code of images2gif I 've used](http://pastebin.com/a1M3ct5W) - I modified it a little bit to make it work with pillow. See comment at the begining of source code.

Comment: Could you provide `count_watermark_position()`?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `images2gif`, but does it make a difference if you convert the composite images to 'RGB' or 'P' mode?

Comment: @adrianus I added code of function to question.

Comment: @snakey Thanks. Where do you get `images2gif.readGifFromPIL()` or what version of `images2gif` are you using? I downloaded the latest [images2gif](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/images2gif) but there's no such method in there. I get it to work with `readGif()` though...

Comment: @PM2Ring If i change `img = Image.open(in_file)` to `img = Image.open(in_file).convert("RGB")`, it looks like information about frames is lost and result is GIF with only first frame (not animated). The same thing happens with 'P' mode. Looks like I cant convert the image before using images2gif.

Comment: @adrianus good point, added link to source code to question. I think method readGifFromPIL is the same as readGif except it doenst take path to image as argument but the file itself. I also edited the code to make it work with pillow (see comment in source code at the beginning)

Comment: @snakey: I wasn't suggesting that you convert the input data. But I _suspect_ it might make a difference if you convert the composite images before you pass them to `images2gif.writeGif`. Eg `frames_out.append(Image.composite(watermark_layer, frame, watermark_layer).convert(mode='RGB'))`

Comment: Very strange, I get the same black-and-white frames for every frame but the first. Maybe an error in `images2gif`?

Comment: @PM2Ring Tried your example. Problem is the same (first frame ok, others not - color incorectness is little different depending on mode RGB or P)

Comment: @adrianus there is a [discussion with similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10269099/pil-convert-gif-frames-to-jpg) where images2gif is not used.